# How to fix meaningless white space in video frame?

Tags: html, css, frontend, removing-whitespace

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8PIFJ.png)
Hello everyone,
I need your help to fix this interesting **white space**. Why does it look this?

Comment: Please, provide a working example of code, you can use stackoverflow code snippet or any live editors like [CodePen](https://codepen.io/).

Comment: Hey @Kumara
Here it is: https://codepen.io/mirzasahin/pen/KKodazw
Thanks for your help! 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `border-width` to an even number, so instead of this:

```css
#video_1 {
    /* ... */
    border-radius: 15px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 5px;
    /* ... */
}
```

Instead use something like `4px` instead of `5px`:

```css
#video_1 {
    /* ... */
    border-radius: 15px;
    border-style: solid;
    /* like this */
    border-width: 4px;
    /* ... */
}
```

Comment: Does this work if the device pixel ratio is not even?

Comment: @AHaworth interesting question, I'm not certain, but quite confident that this shouldn't be true. Since the reason why the odd pixel values weren't working is that renderers tend to round off numbers which leads to extra spaces as seen before. So by using even numbers it helps curb this.

Answer (score 2):

You are seeing a sort of edge effect where the system is struggling to match part CSS pixels to the multiple screen pixels that make up one CSS pixel on modern displays.

If you put a background to the video the same coloring as the border it will 'fill up' the little gap.

```
background-color: rgba(255, 181, 147, 0.814);
```